# Pandas replace indexes of rows according to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called df:

```
             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
dog   jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
      dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
fox   jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
      dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
jumps jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
      the     1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
      over    1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
over  jumps   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      the     1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
      dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
the   jumps   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0
      over    1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
```

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'dog': 1, 'fox': 1, 'the': 2, 'over': 2, 'jumps': 0}
```

I want to replace the values of indexes with their respective values from the dic.

I have tried the following approach:

```
df.index.levels[0][0] = 'integer value'
```

but this doesn't work and it gives me the error:

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

Also the [pandas rename function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) is also not working

Any idea of how to do this in the most efficient and clean way. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 10):

I think `rename` still work

```
df.rename(index=dic)
Out[1311]: 
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10                               
1 0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
```

Comment: How did you make this work, my dataframe still remains the same :(

Comment: just to be clear whats your dic here?

Comment: Oh I made it work! Thanks @Wen

Comment: @Wen, just beware for larger datatframes: [.replace() with a dict about 60x slower than .map().fillna()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12657)

Comment: @Elisha512 aha, cheers

Comment: @jp_data_analysis that is make sense :-) map should be fast

Comment: Works with a series as well, index matching df and values containing new desired indices

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
s = df.index.to_series()
df.index = s.map(dic).fillna(s)
```

For some reason mapping via a dictionary is permitted for a series, but only functions are permitted for an index.

Worked example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 1], ['a', 'c', 2],
                   ['b', 'd', 3], ['b', 'c', 4]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df = df.set_index('A')

print(df.index)
# Index(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object', name='A')

s = df.index.to_series()
df.index = s.map({'a': 'X'}).fillna(s)

print(df.index)
# Index(['X', 'X', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object', name='A')
```

Comment: It just replaces all the row indexes with NaN

Comment: this changes nothing

Comment: @ jp_data_analysis thank you for explaining but its the opposite of what I wanted. I am not trying to replace the values a,a,b,b. Instead, I am trying to replace the row indexes of those values which are: 0,1,2,3

Comment: its not about letters or numbers, its about the position of those letters/numbers